# Storing Javascript Array of Objects in Mongo DB using Mongoose

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an array of the form `[{key: ..., type: ..., value: ...}]` and want to store it in the `fields` field in the following schema:

```
var articleSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true
  },
  updated: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  pageviews: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
  },
  fields: [{
    key: String,
    type: String,
    value: String
  }],
  image: String
});
```

I am doing this as follows, my Javascript array referenced as `keyValueObj`

```
Article.findOneAndUpdate(
  { name: articleName },
  {
    fields: keyValueObj
  },
  { upsert: true },
  callback
);
```

However, all that is stored in the database in the `fields` field is an array of strings like this: `["[object Object]"]`

How can I store my Javascript array so that it matches my mongoose schema correctly?

Comment: You should probably create another schema for fields and then do fields:[fieldsSchema]

Comment: You can parse the array to json or try change de schema type to Array (http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this using [Molda's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3284355/molda) idea of using a separate schema.

The updated `fields` field in the `articleSchema` now looks like this:

```
fields: [{
  type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  ref: 'Field'
}]
```

I then converted the array to an array of schema objects, like this:

```
keyValueObj = keyValueObj.map(function(fieldObj){
  return new Field({
    key: fieldObj.key,
    type: fieldObj.type,
    value: fieldObj.value
  });
});
```

I was then able to store `keyValueObj` the was doing it in the initial code.